# Why do I have to restart NetworkManager.service all the time?

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, systemd

After switching to systemd, I started to use NetworkManager.service, I got connected to WIFI automatically at boot, but I got the following message when I run `nmcli con`:

```
** (process:4433): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist

Error: nmcli (0.9.6.4) and NetworkManager (unknown) versions don't match. Force execution using --nocheck, but the results are unpredictable.
```

And from systemctl:

```
NetworkManager.service                              loaded active running       Network Manager
```

Now if I restart `NetworkManager.service`, it works. Why is that?

Comment: “nmcli (0.9.6.4) and NetworkManager (unknown) versions don't match”. Have you tried fixing that? Where do nmcli and NetworkManager come from?

Comment: @Gilles they both belong to `networkmanager 0.9.6.4-1`, official repository of Arch, and it looks like a DBUS problem

Comment: I have a similar anomaly.  NetworkManager will drop the wireless connection after a while and NetworkManger restart is required. Arch Linux and Gnome 3.6 on systemd

Comment: After deprecating Gnome 3.6 and fresh install of ArchLinux/Xfce 4.1, the problem still occurs.  In addition, after restart of NetworkManager.service, the NetworkManger applet disappears.

Comment: @keepitsimpleengineer i don't know, but the problem disappeared now ... and I don't use a panel

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue and [several bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ppp/+bug/869954) have been submitted.

There is also [a workaround for ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/97774), but I don't think it will work for Arch users because they no longer use init scripts. I bet their fix can be ported but I don't know enough about `systemd` to do it.

Here is [a solution](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=229718#2) from the Fedora forums that looks like it works:

- Right-click on the **NetworkManager** applet
- Edit **Connections**
- Click the **Wireless** tab (if that's what you're using)
- Select your connection and click the **Edit** button
- Go to the **IPv4 Settings** tab
- Click the **Routes** button
- Check "**Use this connection only for resources on its network.**"
- Press OK
- Uncheck "**Available to all users**"
- Press **Save**

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue on CentOS 7 and I did this as root:

```
systemctl mask network
```

That command blocks `network.service`. That is because `network.service` and `NetworkManager.service` do the same thing and sometimes, one service does not allow the other to work fine.